# uncheck the checkbox in checkbox list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I want to uncheck the checkbox from the list of checkbox depending upon the condition.Checkboxes are generated from the ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="col in columns">
    <span class="inputH">
         <input type="checkbox" value="col.name"   ng-if="col.default === true" checked ng-click="onColSelect(col.name,$event)" id="column_{{$index}}">
         <input type="checkbox" value="col.name"  ng-if="col.default === false" ng-click="onColSelect(col.name,$event)" id="column_{{$index}}">
    </span>
    <span class="textH">{{ 'leadOpportunityHeader.' + col.name | translate }}</span>
</li>
```

while cliking each checkbox, I check some condition. If this condition is true then I uncheck the same checkbox.
My question is is it possible to uncheck the checkbox without using `ng-model`?
If its not possile then I need to know how will I do this with the help of ng-model

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ng-checked** to check and uncheck checkbox instead of **ng-model**.

```
ng-checked=true or false
```